# Insert section title within index in ConTeXt

Tags: listings, indentation, context, indexing

## Background

Each recipe in a recipe book has ingredients, and those ingredients can be common for different recipes throughout the book. For example:

[image: Ingredient Index]

## Code

I've added the comma and colours as follows:

```
\definealternativestyle[reg:bigbold][\sansserif\bold][]

\setupregister[index][
  style=reg:bigbold,
  alternative=A,
  color=ColourPrimary,
  pagecolor=ColourPrimary,
  distance=0pt,
  symbol=n,
  pagecommand={\color[ColourBody]{,}\hskip1ex},
]
```

This produces a similar result:

[image: Ingredient List]

## Problem

The difficulty is collecting all the section names for a given ingredient and collating them with their respective page number.

## Question

How would you include the list of section titles indented under the ingredient name?

## Example

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
\definealternativestyle[reg:bigbold][\sansserif\bold][]

\setupregister[index][
  style=reg:bigbold,
  alternative=A,
  distance=0pt,
  symbol=n,
  pagecommand={\color[black]{,}\hskip1ex},
]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
  \completecontent
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
  \startchapter[
    title={Chapter 1},
    reference=sec:chapter-1,
  ]

  \startsection[
    title={Section 1},
    reference=sec:section-1,
  ]

  \startsubsection[
    title={Ingredients},
    reference=sec:ingredients-1,]

      \index{chocolate milk}{chocolate milk}
      \index{milk}{milk}
      \index{butter}{butter}

  \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
  \stopchapter

  \startchapter[
    title={Chapter 2},
    reference=sec:chapter-2,
  ]

  \startsection[
    title={Section 1},
    reference=sec:section-1,]

      \index{milk}{milk}
      \index{egg}{egg}
      \index{ham}{ham}

  \stopsection

  \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
  \chapter{Index}
  \placeindex[compress=yes]
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Is using the ``+`` operator sufficient?
E.g. ``\index{dairy+milk}``, ``\index{dairy+butter}`` etc. (Remove or adjust the line ``distance=0pt`` to get a hanging indent.)

Comment: @phg: Are you suggesting `\index{milk+\currentsectiontitle}{milk}`?

Comment: Yes, after the scheme:
``\index {<ingredient>+<sectiontitle>}``.
Of course you would have to add each section explicitly.

Comment: Here’s a complete example of what I mean: https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/6653790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the question, so I don't know if this answer's your question or not.

```
\define[2]\Index
    {\expanded{\index{#1+\currentstructuretitle}{#2}}}

\starttext

\startsection[title={Everything Buns}]

  \Index{all-purpose flour}{all-purpose flour}
  \Index{olive oil}{olive oil}

  Instructions on how to make buns.

\stopsection

\startsection[title={Butternut Squash Soup}]

  \Index{olive oil}{olive oil}
  \Index{bacon}{bacon}

  Instructions on how to make butternut squash soup.

\stopsection

\placeindex

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: The command was not in the wiki; I have added it. http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/currentstructuretitle